# Slicing an array that contains empty strings

Tags: zsh, array

Consider the array `foo`, initialized like this:

```
$ foo=( a b '' d e f g )
```

`foo` contains 7 elements, one of which is an empty string.

Below are a few ways to print out the contents of `foo`, using the `print` built-in:

```
$ print -rl -- $foo
a
b
d
e
f
g
$ print -rl -- "$foo"
a b  d e f g
$ print -rl -- $foo[@]
a
b
d
e
f
g
$ print -rl -- "$foo[@]"
a
b

d
e
f
g
```

Note that only the form whose last token is `"$foo[@]"` interprets it as 7 separate arguments.

Now, suppose that I wanted to use `print -rl -- ...` to display only the first 5 elements of `foo`, one element per line?

This won't work:

```
$ print -rl -- "$foo[1,5]"
a b  d e
```

Nor this:

```
$ print -rl -- $foo[1,5]
a
b
d
e
```

I've tried other variants, but they all fail to produce the desired output, namely

```
a
b

d
e
```

What's the slice-equivalent of the full `"$foo[@]"`?

If no such equivalent exists, how do I create an array `bar` consisting of the first 5 elements of `foo`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though `zsh` doesn't do split+glob upon parameter expansion, it still does empty removal, so that's still one reason you want to quote variables there, so:

```
print -rl -- "$var[@]"
```

Or

```
print -rl -- "${(@)var}"
```

Those `@` are to get Bourne `"$@"`-like behaviour.

For elements 1 to 5:

```
print -rl -- "${(@)var[1,5]}"
```

The `ksh`-like variant will also work:

```
print -rl -- "${(@)var:0:5}"
```